# Cucumber, Webrat and Selenium NoMethodError in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, cucumber, webrat

I'm having a problem using selenium. When I have a scenario which uses the "I should see foo within bar" web step from cucumber, I get the following error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `within' for #<Webrat::SeleniumSession:0x000000057ea608>
```

It works fine just using cucumber and webrat without selenium.

Here is the webrat configure block from my env.rb:

```
Webrat.configure do |config|
  config.mode = :selenium
  config.application_framework = :rack
  config.open_error_files = false # Set to true if you want error pages to pop up in the browser
end
```

**Here is the step that causes the trouble** (it's implementation is in web_steps.rb)

```
Then I should not see "2" within "#node"
```

Comment: May I nominate 'Then I should not see "2" within "#node"' for DailyWTF as a prime example of Cucumber abuse? Cucumber is for clients to review, and should only say high level things like "this feature is profitable". And Cucumber should NOT be used as a confusion layer over tests that drive a website through its user interface!

Answer (score -1):

Could you post your step? The definition for this is in web_steps.rb

Are you sure your step matches the regexp in this file? AFAIK there should be double quotes around the "foo" and "bar"

Comment: Added the step. The step seems to match up fine, it works perfectly when selenium is not used

Comment: Then I'm not sure. I've not tried the webrat\selenium combination (we use Capybara)